# AWS static website - how to connect subdomains with subfolders

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, static-pages

I want to setup S3 static website and connect with my domain (for example domain: **example.com**).

In this S3 bucket I want to create one particular folder (name **content**) and many different subfolders with in, then I want to connect these subfolders with appropriate subdomains, so for example

- folder **content/foo** should be available from subdomain **foo.example.com**,
- fodler **content/bar** should be available from subdomain **bar.example.com**.

Any **content** subfolder should be automatically available from subdomain with that same prefix name like folder name.
I will be grateful for any possible solutions for this problem. Should I use redirection option or there is any better solution? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution base on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mls8tiiI3uc

Because above video don’t explain subdomain problem, here is few additional things to do:

- to AWS Route53 hostage zone we should add records A with “*.domainname” as record name and edge address as Value
- to certificate domains we should add also “*.domainname”- to have certificate for wildcard domain
- when setting up Cloudfront distribution we should add to “Alternate domain name (CNAME)“ section “www.domainname” and also “*.domainname”
- redirection/forwarding from subdomain to subfolder is realizing via Lambda@Edge function (function should be improve a bit):

```js
'use strict';

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const path = require("path");

    const remove_suffix = ".domain.com";
    const host_with_www = "www.domain.com"
    const origin_hostname = "www.domain.com.s3-website.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    const host_header = headers.host[0].value;
    if (host_header == host_with_www) {
        return callback(null, request);
    }
    if (host_header.startsWith('www')) {
        var new_host_header = host_header.substring(3,host_header.length)
    }
    if (typeof new_host_header === 'undefined') {
        var new_host_header = host_header
    } 
    if (new_host_header.endsWith(remove_suffix)) {
        // to support SPA | redirect all(non-file) requests to index.html
        const parsedPath = path.parse(request.uri);
        if (parsedPath.ext === "") {
        request.uri = "/index.html";
        }
        request.uri =
        "/" +
        new_host_header.substring(0, new_host_header.length - remove_suffix.length) +
        request.uri;
    }

    headers.host[0].value = origin_hostname;
    return callback(null, request);
    
};
```

- Lambda@Edge is just Lambda function connected with particular Cloudfront distribution
- need to add to Cloudfront distribution additional setting for Lambda execution (this setting is needed if we want to have different redirection for different subdomian, instead all redirection will point to main directory or probably to first directory which will be cached - first request to our Cloudfront domain):
  [image]